# Does Spring Data REST support reactive crud repositories?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-data-rest, spring-webflux

I've got really simple and standard OrderRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="orders", path="orders")
public interface OrderRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Order, String> {
}
```

After hitting the server with:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/orders
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
{"cause":null,"message":"reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable"}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, not yet. Follow [this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-933) for progress on that topic.

Comment: FYI, and the issue has been declined.